Grails spring security plugin convert 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' to type 'Filter'
Error creating bean with name 'filterInvocationInterceptorDeregistrationBean': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor' to required type 'javax.servlet.Filter' for property 'filter'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor' to required type 'javax.servlet.Filter' for property 'filter': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
To Reproduce
Create a new grails project with embedded tomcat
Add following grails spring security plugins to build.gradle:
spring-security-core, spring-security-ldap, spring-security-ui
Declare authManager bean in resources.groovy like so:
@bean
AuthenticationManager authManager(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory factory = new LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory(contextSource);
factory.setUserDnPatterns("uid={0},DC=edapt,DC=local");
return factory.createAuthenticationManager();
}

Import core spring security libraries (not plugins) spring-security-core, spring-security-web and spring-security-config in build.gradle
Attempt to run the app
Expected behavior
The app should run and connect to Active Directory over LDAP
